# Update background image of a table without 'flickering'

Tags: javascript, image, refresh

I use a JavaScript script to update the background image of a table. The table and image are used for updating "motion detection cells" on a camera. The table is used to store some data in for motion detection, for each cell.

To see what cells need to change, I update the background image of the table ever 2 seconds or so, but the image flickers. In another HTML page, if I update an image  placed in an `img` tag, it doesn't flicker but just seems to update the image, while in the table it looks like the image is erased and the new one is used as the background

Is there a way to change that behavior for a table background image? (I thought about putting the table on top of an `img` element, and then refresh the image.)

Comment: Preload the image to ensure it is in the cache

Answer (score 0):

Like someone said in the comments... you could preload the image. A lot of browsers do that already under the hood.

### My advice to this solution:

`<table>` is something I would not consider using in this case. I'd actually go for `<canvas>` element and create a grid using 2D or 3D context (WebGL), because it seems to be a realtime problem. And when it comes to dynamic stuff - canvas wins because it doesn't have to set up all the listerners for each element and all that CSS layer stuff.

For example:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

let img = new Image()
img.onload = image => {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 100, 100)
    // Logic here

}
img.src = '/path/to/image.jpg'
```

Remember to make this code more clean and scalable. This is just a simple example how to draw an image on canvas.

If you are not familiar with CanvasAPI I highly recommend diving deep in this topic because it opens a lot of new possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with, since I was already able to refresh an image in an IMG tag without flickering.

I created a div, same size as the images/table and positioned to image at 0, 0   and  positioned the table at 0, 0 also.